# Is there any function in excel to find day time between two date and time in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, excel-dates

I need a formula to calculate between two date and time excluding lunch time, holidays, weekend and between 09:00 and 18:00 work hours.

For example, 25/07/2022 12:00 and 29/07/2022 10:00 and answer has to be 1 day, 06:00

Thanks in advance.

I had a formula but it didn't work when hours bigger than 24 hours.

Comment: Did you explore `NETWORKDAYS.INTL()`? [Microsoft Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28#:~:text=INTL%20function,-Excel%20for%20Microsoft&text=Returns%20the%20number%20of%20whole,are%20not%20considered%20as%20workdays.)

Comment: lunch time and holydais are affected by your location. It's not the same in all countries so there is no native function for that. You'll need to customize that part and handle it. Anyways., what have you tried? How is your input and expected output? please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Also consider getting an output in a single unit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you got to 1 day and 6 hours, but here is a customizable way to filter your time difference calculation:

```
=LET(
    start,E3,
    end,E4,
    holidays,$B$3:$B$5,
    array,SEQUENCE(INT(end)-INT(start)+1,24,INT(start),TIME(1,0,0)),
    crit_1,array>=start,
    crit_2,array<=end,
    crit_3,WEEKDAY(array,2)<6,
    crit_4,HOUR(array)>=9,
    crit_5,HOUR(array)<=18,
    crit_6,HOUR(array)<>13,
    crit_7,ISERROR(MATCH(DATE(YEAR(array),MONTH(array),DAY(array)),holidays,0)),
    result,SUM(crit_1*crit_2*crit_3*crit_4*crit_5*crit_6*crit_7),
    result
)
```

### Limitation

This solution only works on an hourly level, i.e. the start and end dates and times will only be considered on a full hour basis. When providing times like 12:45 as input, the 15 minute increment won't be accounted for.

### Explanation

The 4th item in the LET() function `SEQUENCE(INT(end)-INT(start)+1,24,INT(start),TIME(1,0,0))` creates an array that contains all hours within the start and end date of the range:

[image]
(transposed for illustrative purposes)

then, based on that array, the different 'crit_n' statements are the individual criteria you mentioned. For example, `crit_1,array>=start` means that only the dates and times after the start date and time will be counted, or `crit_6,HOUR(array)<>13` is the lunch break (assuming the 13th hour is lunch time), ...

All of the individual crit_n's are then arrays of the same size containing TRUE and FALSE elements.

At the end of the LET() function, by multiplying all the individual crit_n arrays, the product returns a single array that will then only contain those hours where all individual criteria statements are TRUE:

[image]

So then the SUM() function is simply returning the total number of hours that fit all criteria.

### Example

I assumed lunch hour to be hour 13, and I assumed the 28th to be a holiday within the given range. With those assumptions and the other criteria you already specified above, I'm getting the following result:

[image]

Which looks like this when going into the formula bar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cell `G2`, you can put the following formula:

```
=LET(from,A2:A4,to,B2:B4,holidays,C2:C2,startHr,E1,endHr,E2, lunchS, E3, lunchE, E4, 
  CALC, LAMBDA(date,isFrom, LET(noWkDay, NETWORKDAYS(date,date,holidays)=0,
    IF(noWkDay, 0, LET(d, INT(date), start, d + startHr, end, d + endHr,
      noOverlap, IF(isFrom, date > end, date < start), lunchDur, lunchE-lunchS,
      ls, d + lunchS, le, d + lunchE,
      isInner, IF(isFrom, date > start, date < end),
      diff, IF(isFrom, end-date-1 - IF(date < ls, lunchDur, 0), 
        date-start-1 - IF(date > le, lunchDur, 0)),
      IF(noOverlap, -1, IF(isInner, diff, 0)))))),
  MAP(from,to,LAMBDA(ff,tt, LET(wkdays, NETWORKDAYS(ff,tt,holidays),
    duration, wkdays + CALC(ff, TRUE) + CALC(tt, FALSE),
    days, INT(duration), time, duration - TRUNC(duration),
    TEXT(days, "d") &" days "& TEXT(time, "hh:mm") &" hrs "
  )))
)
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

Used `LET` function for easy reading and composition. The main idea is first to calculate the number of working days excluding `holidays` **from** column value to **to** column value. We use for that `NETWORKDAYS` function. Once we have this value for each row, we need to adjust it considering the first day and last day of the interval, in case we cannot count as a full day and instead considering hours. For inner days (not start/end of the interval) it is counted as an entire day.

We use `MAP` function to do the calculation over all values of `from` and `to` names. For each corresponding value (`ff`, `tt`) we calculate the working days (`wkdays`). Once we have this value, we use the user `LAMBDA` function `CALC` to adjust it. The function has a second input argument `isFrom` to consider both scenarios, i.e. adjustment at the beginning of the interval (`isFrom = TRUE`) or to the end of the interval (`isFrom=FALSE`). The first input argument is the given `date`.

In case the input `date` of `CALC` is a non working day, we don't need to make any adjustment. We check it with the name `noWkDay`. If that is not the case, then we need we need to determine if there is no overlap (`noOverlap`):

```
IF(isFrom, date > end, date < start)
```

where `start`, `end` names correspond to the same date as `date`, but with different hours corresponding to **start Hr** and **end Hr** (`E1:E2`). For example for the first row, there is no overlap, because the end date doesn't have hour information, i.e. (`12:00 AM`), in such case the corresponding date should not be taken into account and `CALC` returns `-1`, i.e. one day needs to be subtracted.

In case we have overlap, then we need to consider the case the working hours are lower than the maximum working hours (from `9:00` to `18:00`). It is identified with the name `isInner`. If that is the case, we calculate the actual hours. We need to subtract `1` because it is going to be one less full working day and instead to consider the corresponding hours (that should be less than `9hrs`, which is the maximum workday duration). The calculation is carried under the name `diff`:

```
IF(isFrom, end-date-1 - IF(date < ls, lunchDur, 0), 
   date-start-1 - IF(date > le, lunchDur, 0))
```

If the actual start is before the start of the lunch time (`ls`), then we need to subtract lunch duration (`lunchDur`). Similarly if the actual end is is after lunch time, we need to discount it too.

Finally, we use `CALC` to calculate the interval `duration`:

```
wkdays + CALC(ff, TRUE) + CALC(tt, FALSE)
```

Once we have this information, it is just to put in the specified format indicating days and hours.

Now let's review some of the sample input data and results:

- The interval starts on Monday `7/25` and ends on Friday `7/29`, therefore we have `5` working days, but `7/26` is a holiday, so the maximum number of working days will be `4` days.
- For the interval `[7/25, 7/29]` starts and ends on midnight (`12:00 AM`), therefore the last day of the interval should not be considered, so actual working days will be `3`.
- Interval `[7/25 10:00, 7/29 17:00]`. For the start of the interval we cannot count one day, instead `8hrs` and for the end of the interval, the same situation `8hrs`, so instead of `4days` we are goin to have `2days` plus `16hrs`, but we need to subtract in both cases the lunch duration (`1hr`) so the final result will be `2 days 14hrs`.